# Jquery Slide Left to Right

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Kz/2/   mine doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.mybutton').click(function() {
   var $lefty = $(this).next();
   $lefty.animate({
     left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
     -$lefty.outerWidth() :
     0
   });
 });
```

});

help in customizing this code that i got from http://examples.learningjquery.com/slide/

basically i just want to imitate this [effect](http://gosystems.com.au/) "Customer Service"

Comment: why dont you try animate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $lefty = $(this).next();
```

`$(this)` is the last child (`.mybutton`) and `next()` will return nothing, so `$lefty` will be empty.

```
var $lefty = $(this).parent();
```

should work better (if I understood you correctly).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Kz/6/)

Comment: thanks for this, i have updated it..  http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Kz/5/   but i don't want the 'slide it' button to be hidden when i push it back.  how can i do that?

Comment: Maybe something like this then: http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Kz/6/
not to hide `slide it` completely?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#slideleft .mybutton').click(function() {
    var $marginLefty = $(this).parent();
      $marginLefty.animate({
      marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
      $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
      0
    });
  });  
});
```

[Demo: **LEFT TO RIGHT**](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8Kz/7/)

Answer (score 0):

your html is not matching your js, **next** refers to the next element while you have it as previous, you should either replace it with **prev** or just **rearrange** your html, and left works with positioning css. but since you wanted that effect, the animation is applied on the parent there.

```
<div id="slideleft" class="slide">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="mybutton">SLIDE IT</div>
        <div class="scontent" style="position:absolute">Animate this element's left style property</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cls"></div>
```